# Filter on variable of ManyToMany-field inside Django Template

Tags: python, django, pagination

I have a job-object and a content-object.

A job object gets created when a user wants to retrieve a set of content-objects in exchange for credits.

models.py:

```
class JobId(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    job_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class content(models.Model):
    job_id_list = models.ManyToManyField(JobId , related_name='JobId', blank=True)
    job_id_list_not_provided = models.ManyToManyField(JobId , related_name='JobIdFailed', blank=True)
    free_content = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    paying_content = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
```

For all content-objects part of the job, the JobId-object is added to the job_id_list - not keeping credit levels in mind. Different user can all run multiple jobs on the content objects.

For too-big jobs exceeding the credit amount of the user, the content-objects that would push the credit level below zero, get also the JobID-object added to the job_id_list_not_provided field of the  content-object.

For a a specific user, we can retrieve the two sub-sets of found and not-found content-objects with following queries:

views.py:

```
found_results_list     = results_list.filter(job_id_list_not_provided__user= None).distinct()
not_found_results_list = results_list.filter(job_id_list_not_provided__user=request.user).distinct()
```

My challenge:

Result lists are over 100-objects in size, so I would like to use pagination to get a nice view on my page

When not considering pagination, I could simply pass the 2 lists (found and not found) and loop over each list with a template from django:

Html:

```
<table>
    <body>
        {% for result in found_results_list %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{result.free_content}}</td>
                <td>{{result.paying_content}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% empty %}
            <tr>no result</tr>
        {% endfor %}
        {% for result in not_found_results_list %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{result.free_content}}</td>
                <td>pay for the content</td>
            </tr>
        {% empty %}
            <tr>no result</tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But what to do if I want to use pagination? It seems you can only use one result-list.

views.py 
(I used `.distinct()` as sometimes the objects have too much jobs added to it from the same user)

```
results_list =  xlinkdatabase_validated.objects.filter(job_id_list__user=request.user).distinct()
```

**Main problem is:**

I don't know to check inside the template if the paying_content can be visible if is start from an overall `result_list` both including found and not_found objects.

I tried using `{{result.job_id_list_not_provided}}` template inside Html, but this returns all job-objects of the content-object, even if these are not related to the specific user, which is logic of course.

How would I tackle this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Two solutions come to my mind, first one is to use subquery to get the filtered result and the second one is using chain to combine both queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually solved my own issue by building a custom template tag that I unleash on my content-objects inside my view.

extra tags.py:

```
from django import template
from frontendapp.models import *

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def has_viewing_rights(result, user):
    has_viewing_rights = True
    job_id_list_not_providedd = result.job_id_list_not_provided.all()
    for item in job_id_list_not_providedd:
        if item.user == user:
            has_viewing_rights = False
    return has_viewing_rights
```

html:

```
{% if result|has_viewing_rights:request.user%}
    provided
{%else%}
    not provided
{%endif%}
```